# Symfony 6 routing 404 на корневой странице

Tags: symfony, маршрутизация

А контроллере указываю аннотации с роутами:

```
    #[Route('/date-{type}', name: 'app_sitemapHtml_empty')]
    public function index_empty(
        $type = 'all',
    ): Response {
        $date = '2003-01-01';
        return $this->getByDay($type, $date);
    }

    #[Route('/date-{type}/{date}', name: 'app_sitemapHtml')]
    public function index(
        $type = 'all',
        $date = '2003-01-01',
    ): Response {
        return $this->getByDay($type, $date);
    }
```

На app_sitemapHtml_empty всегда выдаёт 404 ошибку.

Не совсем понимаю где проблема.
Ещё когда я пытаюсь перейти /date-org/, автоматически удаляется последний слеш, хотя в других местах этого не происходит (нет никаких доп настроек), кеши почистил.

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь, на соседнем контроллере стоял /{name} роут, который перекрывал /date-{type}.